# Changing playback rate of AVPlayer produces choppy Audio

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer, avplayeritem, playback-rate

I am using AVPlayer in my app. My app supports the change of speed of playback of audio and video. I am initializing the player as follows.

```
 AVPlayerItem * playerItem= [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:self.audioUrl];
     playerItem.audioTimePitchAlgorithm = AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmSpectral;
     self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
        self.player.allowsExternalPlayback= YES;
[self.player.currentItem addObserver:self
                                  forKeyPath:@"status"
                                     options:0
                                     context:nil];
```

and when i have to change the playback rate of audio i do as follows

```
self.player.rate = 2.0f;
```

It was working fine. But recently when i change the rate property of AVPlayer it start producing choppy voice. I already have set the `audioTimePitchAlgorithm`  to

```
AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmSpectral
```

but still it producing choppy voice. 
Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong, or what i have to do to avoid this  choppy voice and to produce smooth sound.

Comment: Its not helpful as it is related to AVAudioPlayer while i am asking for AVPlayer. Also setEnableRate is not property of AVPlayer

Comment: Have you tried set `audioTimePitchAlgorithm` to `AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmLowQualityZeroLatency`?  might be the latency which causing choppy?

Comment: i Tried this but this produced poor quality sound

Comment: if you tried ZeroLatency which was only caused poor quality but without latency, so it **possible** because of the latency which causing choppy. so how about using `AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmTimeDomain` ? not sure this would solve this issue, but at least can locate the core of this issue?